# Система регистрации

Tags: java, android-studio, архитектура, регистрация

Всем привет. В общем, мне нужно сделать регистрацию в приложении. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно ее располагать? В главной активности (MainActivity) я должен вставлять весь код, связанный с самой авторизацией/регистрацией (окошка входа/регистрации), а потом уже (при успешной авторизации) вызывать активность, отвечающую за основу приложения (меню, какие-то кнопки, короче главный экран приложения)? И да, не могли бы посоветовать какие-то сервисы, или даже лучше уроки, в которых это хорошо рассказывается на русском языке? Если, конечно, не затруднит.

Спасибо большое заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Активити реги/авторизации делаешь за основную в манифесте, далее при успешном входе или регистрации запускаешь новую активити (которая будет за основную) и уничтожая при этом активити реги/авторизации. По поводу сервисов могу подсказать лишь два сайта [раз](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru) [два](https://developer.android.com/)

Comment: А что, если у меня основная в манифесте - экран загрузки? Из него вызывать уже окно авторизации?

Comment: Я так понял ты про Splash, конечно можно

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое :)